# Web app to check a web page for given text and send an email when detected

Tags: webapp-rec

I need a web app that can automatically check a given web page everyday for given text, and if it detects the text inside the page, send me an email.  I am not asking for a service monitoring the changes but monitoring a page for the desired text. The page can change everyday, every hour, but that word does not always appear.

Is there such a web service?

Comment: You could try [ifttt](http://ifttt.com/)

Comment: @Alex: I heard about it but do you know if it can do that for sure?

Comment: To be honest, no. That's why I haven't post it as an answer. But you are looking for a custom set of actions and that's exactly the purpose of ifttt - to allow you to build custom triggers - so I think you should give it a try.

Comment: I signed up and checked but it only has predefined *Channels* (popular web services like Facebook, Gmail, Weather Channel, etc.) that provide triggers. So it won't work for any given web page.

Comment: the closest trigger in ifttt apply to a rss feed, not a random page: "This trigger fires every time a new item in the feed you specify contains a particular keyword or simple phrase."

Comment: If you'd like I could build this tool for you, it would only take a couple minutes. I have no qualms scheduling a simple script like this to run hourly and email you whenever the the text appears on the web page, it'd be run from a reliable server at a colo facility. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: i found this site interesting: http://www.montastic.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
curl -s http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ | grep twitter &&
mail -s "website references twitter" youremail@company.com  </dev/null
```

This will send an email to youremail@company.com when "twitter" appears anywhere on webapps.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: Can I use the above code on Windows 7? If yes, how?

Comment: No. Not unless you download cygwin.

Answer (score 6):

Using http://www.watchthatpage.com create a channel, add the URL(s) of the page(s) to monitor and then enable keyword matching via Edit Properties.

Answer (score 2):

I use [ChangeDetection.com](http://changedetection.com). It is free, but only has daily mails, so no real-time monitoring. Other than that, it has been working really well for several years.

Answer (score 0):

I use Montastic.

its nice, because you can setup a url and also a presence or absence of a keyword.

there you can monitor with the free plan up to 3 active URLs every 30 minutes (unlimited inactive URLs).

with paid plans you can monitor every 5 minutes and you can increase the active URLs for monitoring.

and there is also an API and an iPhone App to manage the settings.

Homepage with detailed feature list: http://www.montastic.com

Disclaimer: i am a user of this service at free plan

Comment: The link you listed doesn't list the keyword feature you mentioned here. Is there a better link? Also, can you add a disclaimer regarding any link you have to montastic? Examples: Owner, employee, investor, user, etc.

Comment: its here: "What are the features? [...] NEW! Verify presence or absence of keyword on a web page' - also you see it in the video

Comment: PS: added disclaimer