# Using IFTTT to scrape a site - Court Forms

Tags: if-this-then-that

I'm wondering if there's a way to watch a website for changes, even if the site doesn't have a web feed.  Specifically, I'd like to watch various state's court form websites for updated forms.  http://www.courts.ca.gov/formnumber.htm  So you'll see on that page, a form number (adopt-200), and a date revised (7/1/2010).

I'd like to use IFTTT (or something similar... hopefully I don't have to make my own, but whatever) to notify me if there is a change to any of the forms on that page, and then download the new pdf file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done a web search for "[web page monitor](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+page+monitor)"? There are any number of sites offering this service.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19128/webapp-to-check-a-web-page-for-given-text-and-send-an-email-when-detected